# .NET Core 6 enable CORS to allow Sveltekit front app requests

Tags: .net, backend, sveltekit

I'm building a project with two applications: .NET 6 for backend purposes and Sveltekit for frontend app. So, in this example, I'm requesting to Sveltekit endpoint /api/login wiht POST method:

```
    <script lang="ts">
  import { Input } from "$ui/input";
  import { Button } from "$ui/button";
  import { t } from "$lib/translations";

  let email: string;
  let password: string;

  const doLogin = async (event: Event) => {
    const form = document.querySelector("form") as HTMLFormElement;
    const data = new FormData(form);

    let formResponse = await fetch("/api/login", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
    });
  };
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={doLogin} method="POST" class="w-full px-10">
  <Input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" bind:value={email} />
  <Input
    type="password"
    class="mt-5"
    name="password"
    placeholder="Password"
    bind:value={password}
  />
  <Button class="mt-5 orange">{$t("login.login")}</Button>
</form>
```

And this is the Sveltekit endpoint, which calls to .NET endpoint to request an access token, verify credentials and all this stuff...

Sveltekit endpoint:

```
    import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { RequestHandler } from '../users/$types';

export const POST: RequestHandler = async ({ request }) => {
    
    const formData = await request.formData();
    
    let email = formData.get('email');
    let password = formData.get('password');    

    if (email === null || password === null) {
        return false;
    }

    email = encodeURIComponent(email as string);
    password = encodeURIComponent(password as string);
        
    let serverResponse = await fetch(`https://localhost:7018/api/users/login`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password,
        })
    })
    
    return json({});
};
```

`.NET Endpoint`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Taraka.Models.DTO;
using Taraka.Context;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;
using taraka.Models.DTO.Users;
using Taraka.Models.DTO.Users;
using Taraka.Services;
using Taraka.Authentication;
using Taraka.Classes;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;

namespace Taraka.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("/api/users/")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private ILogger _logger;
    private IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly TarakaContext _tarakaContext;
    private readonly UserService _userService;

    public UserController(TarakaContext tarakaContext, ILogger<UserController> logger, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _tarakaContext = tarakaContext;
        _config = config;
        _userService = new UserService(_tarakaContext, _config);
    }


.
.
.

    [EnableCors("AllowTarakito")]
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public ResponseJSON Login([FromBody] LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        try
        {
            string email = loginModel.Email;
            string password = loginModel.Password;

            User user = _userService.FindByEmail(email);

            if (user is null)
            {
                return new ResponseJSON
                {
                    Success = false,
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                    Body = new JsonObject
                    {
                        { "message", "Oops! Credenciales incorrectas" }
                    }
                };
            }

            if (!AuthenticatorHandler.VerifyCredentials(email, password, user.Password, user.Salt))
            {
                return new ResponseJSON
                {
                    Success = false,
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                    Body = new JsonObject
                    {
                        { "message", "Oops! Credenciales incorrectas" }
                    }
                };
            }

            string token = _userService.GetAccessToken(email);

            return new ResponseJSON
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Success = true,
                Body = new JsonObject()
                {
                    { "token", token }
                }
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new ResponseJSON
            {
                Body = new ErrorMessageHandler(e, _logger).GetMessage(),
                Success = false,
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
            };
        }

    }
```

So, in `Program.cs` CORS is enabled on this way:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(opt =>
    {
        opt.AddPolicy(
            builder.Configuration["CORS:PolicyName"],
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }
        );
    }
);

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseCors(builder.Configuration["CORS:PolicyName"]);

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

When `Sveltekit` try to fetch to `.NET` this is the error log:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at fetch (C:\Users\alexx\dev\erp-template\tarakito\node_modules\undici\index.js:109:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async POST (C:\Users\alexx\dev\erp-template\tarakito\src\routes\api\login\+server.ts:18:23)    
    at async Module.render_endpoint (C:\Users\alexx\dev\erp-template\tarakito\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\endpoint.js:42:20)
    at async resolve (C:\Users\alexx\dev\erp-template\tarakito\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:377:17)
    at async Object.handle (C:\Users\alexx\dev\erp-template\tarakito\src\hooks.server.ts:54:12)       
    at async Module.respond (C:\Users\alexx\dev\erp-template\tarakito\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:248:20)
    at async file:///C:/Users/alexx/dev/erp-template/tarakito/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:513:22
```

I don't really know what is happening... :(

Comment: Can you show value of `builder.Configuration["CORS:PolicyName"]`?

Comment: Yes, the value is "AllowTarakito" @jhmckimm

Comment: Can you also move your `.UseCors()` call to *before* `.UseAuthentication()`?

Comment: Same error @jhmckimm